# Check which script create a file in /tmp

Tags: linux, apache

I got some malware or hack in my debian. I see process in top which took 300% of processor load. How can i check which script or which user creating this file over and over again, i can kill this process but in next 30 min this process will renew.

This process is: `/tmp/phpmnE0Ib_jhikt717dscrcw6b -c 2 -M stratum+tcp://4AE9fi43498hg 938hg....3o4ijf3ioEI0:x@monerohash.com:3333/xmr`

and user of this process is my apache (www-data).

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs on Stack Overflow, consider https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is no sure or easy way find what is causing this.  Worse still, if you do find what keeps running this script, AND get rid of the immediate problem, you STILL can't be sure that 1) the "hole" they got in through has been plugged and 2) they haven't installed a rootkit or backdoor for that they can get back in at a later date.

The best advice is:

- Shutdown the compromised system
- Snapshot / preserve its file system.
- Use known secure system to forensically examine the compromised file system.  You should be looking for evidence to identify the vulnerability (or bad security practice!!) that lead to the compromise.
- Once you have positively the cause of the problem:

  - Build a new version of the system from a **known** clean base image (e.g. installation discs) and up-to-date copies of all of your software, obtained from **known** clean sources.
  - Restore files and database state from a backup that is **known** to be clean; i.e. taken prior to the compromise.

It is unwise to attempt to "clean out" a compromised system.  Unless you are extremely skilled in forensic security AND extremely diligeny, you can never be sure that you have gotten rid of hidden backdoors, etc that the bad guys might have left.  Expert hackers are good at hiding their tracks ... and leading false trails / false clues to make you think you have figured it out.

Comment: Yes, I read a lot about it. Exploits can generally be identified but still always theoretical uncertainty that the hole does not exist. Now I will reinstall the entire server and reinstall it. Now I have more knowledge about server configuration what i will use during its installation and it will probably help with security issues such as apache, iptables, etc.